# Monodromy, Holonomy and Braiding Phase

Tags: conformal-field-theory, quantum-hall-effect, berry-pancharatnam-phase

In quantum Hall effect, especially in the context of CFT description, these words come up often. I think I understand the braiding phase - as the phase gained by the wave function when a quasi particle is adiabatically moved around another one. Quite similar to the Berry phase if one thinks of the location of the quasi particle in the 2D plane as the parameter space.

But what are the monodromy and holonomy phases ? Are they physically measurable quantities ?